# Cannot add IdentityRole - InvalidRoleName

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core, asp.net-roles

I am trying to Create an Identity Role in ASP .NET Core. When I try to create a role, I am getting this error message and the value is not getting inserted.

Output:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:4313/Admin/Roles/Create application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 182
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executing action method AuditLab.Web.Areas.Admin.Controllers.RolesController.Create (AuditLab.Web) with arguments () - ModelState is Valid
I am here
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager:Warning: Role 1d7d78bf-963a-4275-ab67-f9b62342bd78 validation failed: InvalidRoleName.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ViewResultExecutor:Information: Executing ViewResult, running view at path /Areas/Admin/Views/Roles/Create.cshtml.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action AuditLab.Web.Areas.Admin.Controllers.RolesController.Create (AuditLab.Web) in 11.845ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 18.4453ms 200 text/html; charset=utf-8
```

P.S : *I am here* part is to verify the action is running

**UPDATE:**
I discovered that the value that is getting passed to the controller is empty/null. I am using this in my view.

`@model string`

Comment: ... and are you sure that roleName is valid? can you inspect the value that you are passing to RoleManager.Create method?

Comment: For some reason the string value from the model is returned as null/empty.